# rt.jar Java Scan on Red Hat Server

Tags: java, linux

I'm looking for a way to run a scan of all rt.jar on my Red Hat 6 server and then find out what version of java I'm using in each of these directories. I notice sometimes if the directory doesn't list the version on the folder I'm at lost. I assume I can use ' sudo find / -name rt.jar ' to find all the rt.jar but how can I check each java version of these rt.jar files ?

```
Example :
[admin:/ryan/vacation-linux/bin]
(admin)$ sudo find / -name rt.jar
/ryan/jre1.8.0_171_linux/lib/rt.jar
/bob/jre1.6.0_171_linux/lib/rt.jar
/charles/java/lib/rt.jar
```

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 1):

Use `find` combined with `awk` to generate a `java -version` command to run:

```
sudo find /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines -name rt.jar | awk -v OFS='/' -F '/' '{$(NF)="" ; printf("echo %s && %s../bin/java -version && echo && echo\n", $0, $0)}' | sh
```

For me, that prints:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)


/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/
java version "1.8.0_141"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_141-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.141-b15, mixed mode)


/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)


/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```